# Difference in Running Time on Leet Code

Tags: python, performance

While practicing on Leet Code, I came up with my solution which was almost identical to the solution with the best running time. However, the difference in running time was significant.

So as a test I made a submission with the same exact code as the best solution and the running time increased rather decreasing.

Problem is to identify if a given list has any duplicates.
Following is the best solution posted with running time 41ms. My submission with the same code has a running time of 82ms.

```
class Solution(object):
    def containsDuplicate(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: bool
        """

        if nums == []:
            return False

        s = set(nums)
        return len(s) != len(nums)
```

https://leetcode.com/problems/contains-duplicate/description/

Since I just started with leet code and trying to understand if my solutions are optimum, I want to know how leet code calculates the running time and can we trust it to judge the performance of our solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible that the same code was tested with two different input lists? If for example the length of the lists is different, that would potentially affect both of the last two lines linearly in execution time.

Comment: Both my submission had 18 test cases involved. I don't know if the lists were randomly generated in the test cases. Since the test cases were provided by leet code and they are using it to judge the performance, I believe the test cases would be static.

Comment: It's possible that the 41ms you're quoting is from Python3 which, if you run the same code results in around that runtime.  (I tested both, Python2 came to ~90ms pretty consistently while Python3 came to ~46ms).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

40ms difference is way too low to take seriously. The python runtime takes about that long to fire up. Architectural changes LeetCode might have made to their testing suit, python interpreter, etc. are the most likely suspect for this performance disparity. After all, you submitted your solution today while the other solution was submitted a while ago.

Comment: In my expereince, leetcode produces pretty consistent runtimes for a given script (+/- 5ish ms)

Comment: That seems to be the problem. I consulted leet code about the issue. It seems to be a known issue as their infrastructure is not consistent. Well, thanks for your answers.

Comment: I have had similar experience - inconsistency in infra seems to be producing results of even 60% difference for _the same_ code ran in an interval of a few seconds.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with a Java solution. I implemented almost an identical solution to the one with the fastest runtime, and running the same code 3 times gave me 3 different runtime results: 88ms, 104ms, and 74ms. Even though the runtime difference isn't that significant, it made a big impact on my % compared to other online submissions. (from better than 23% of submissions at 104ms to better than 94% at 74ms). If you're focusing on where your solution stands compared to other submissions, I would take it with a grain of salt since it can greatly vary based on slight runtime variations.

Comment: Same here. Just resubmitting my C++ solution w/o any changes produced different runtime results: from 4ms (99.89%) to 16ms (54.73%). They probably should prepare test data more carefully to avoid such fast run times and hence such wide scatter.

Answer (score 1):

Running time always depends on the input provided to the code. Some sites have a random code to generate the test cases. It may be due to this in your case, running time is more; try to run it several times and then compare the pattern, if it is same, then you can report it to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Posted three scripts to the same assignment and got the following:

1: My original script: 72s runtime. 
2: The "best" script (example of 54 sec runtime): 75s runtime. 
3: Reposted my original script with no changes: 80s runtime.

It is quite random, it cannot differentiate between its best and an average script sometimes :P